# Select from table, if end is reached select from start in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to take a table and select 10 records from a start point but if the end of table is reached, go back to the start? So a table of 100 records, selecting 10 starting at record 95 would being 95-100 and 1-4.

Comment: Sure, Union select top and select bottom or make smart use of row number. what had you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a column with the record number, then you can use arithmetic to define the ordering:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (recnum + (100 - 95)) % 100) ;
```

If not:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join (select count(*) as cnt from t) x
order by (recnum + (x.cnt - 95)) % x.cnt) ;
```

If your records are not sequentially numbered, then you can add the number:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by recnum) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
order by (seqnum + (cnt - 95)) % cnt) ;
```